# PS4 Voice Chat workaround

Tags: networking, proxy, ps4

**Problem**

Currently unable to use the voice chat feature for parties on the PS4.

**Equipment List**

- PS4
- Linksys WRT1900ac (stock firmware, current main router)
- Linksys WRT54GL (DD-WRT firmware, backup router)
- Linode (remote Linux server)

**Background**

I'm currently using a small ISP that caters to small business and apartment complexes (provided by the complex, only alternative would be $60/month, with a data cap **&** slower speeds).  After a few hours of debugging and a couple phone calls I was able to confirm that the ISP blocks the ports used by the PS4 for voice chat, and is unwilling to open them.  Due to this, when testing the internet connection, the PS4 would classify the NAT as type 3.

I'm currently using a VPN connection from my router to allow the full use of my ps4, but it's slow, with high ping times.  I'm willing to switch services to a more powerful/fast VPN service, but as I don't need the features of a VPN, this is merely a quick & dirty way of getting what I want (and at this point, I'm invested enough I'd like to know what I'm missing).

Per the [Sony Network Support Site](http://manuals.playstation.net/document/en/ps4/settings/nw_test.html) for the PS4, the following ports are required (haven't confirmed if these are only required ports).

- TCP:

  - 80
  - 443
  - 3480
- TCP & UPD:

  - 3478
  - 3479

I've configured my linode with a [Squid proxy](http://www.squid-cache.org/), and the PS4 was able to connect with it's native support, but voice service was still unavailable (received an error about NAT restrictions).  I've also looked into using iptables on my DDWRT router to redirect the traffic on a different port (ones the ISP hasn't blocked) to my linode, where I would send the traffic on after redirecting it to the original port.

**Questions**

1. Should I stick with a proxy or try a different setup/service?

   1. If I stay with the proxy, do I keep squid, or try a SOCKS5 proxy?
   2. If I don't stay with the proxy, what do you recommend?  I'll pay for a service if that's what it takes, but I'd prefer to learn to do it manually.
2. Base question about proxies.  From what I understand, it will proxy web traffic, but does it do anything else (traffic sent through other ports)?

Answer (score -1):

I'm no pro but proxies can be sent through any port. There is a TSocks5 setup with Tor but was found to leak DNS info so people suggest privoxy now. There are also things called packet editing proxies which can strip headers on the fly and put new dst ip's or other modifying of packets such as I'm assuming changing MTU and squashing your connection or prevent packets from entering etc.